# Redirect (headers already sent); I know they're sent, but how do I re-organize this to make sense?

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have an INDEX that calls "header.php" prior to loading the actual pages like so:

```
include 'includes/header.php';

    if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
        include'includes/pages/page.php';
    }
```

And then, in this page, I want the user to be able to "add a new page" (from index.php?add_page=1) and then redirect them to "edit the page they just created" (from index.php?edit_page=).

```
if(isset($_POST['add_page']) && $_POST['add_page'] == 1) {
    if(!$add_user['error']) {
        //header("Location: ".$page_url);
        //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$page_url}';</script>";

    }
}
```

The 'header("Location:")' fails because headers have already been sent (which makes sense to me); but, how is it possible for me to redirect in this post and skip the header since it's redirecting to the edit page without having this code directly in my header.php?

Comment: use ob_start() in first line and ob_end_clean() before header location, and don't forget die() after header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: use javascript instead
    header(Location: yourUrlHere);.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='yourUrlHere';</script>";
```

If you want to be sure that your redirect will happen even the client have javascript disable, use meta:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=yourUrlHere">';
```

"0" is the delay, in seconds, before redirect it will happen.